# Sending Type Parameters like DirectCast

Tags: vb.net

I've made this extension to replace my usage of DirectCast, because i don't find it very readable.

```
<Extension>
Public Function [As](Of T)(Input As Object) As T
    Return DirectCast(Input, T)
End Function

Dim i = (New Integer).As(Of Integer)
```

My problem is the need for "Of" before writing integer.
DirectCast doesn't need that.

```
DirectCast(New Integer, Integer)
```

How can i change my code to have the same appearance as DirectCast's type parameter?

Essentially looking like this:

```
Dim i = (New Integer).As(Integer)
```

Comment: But `DirectCast` *does* need a second parameter. Either way you need to specify the Type to cast to.

Comment: @Plutonix I didn't ask for it not having the second parameter, i asked how to remove the "Of" part from my code to mimic the behavior of DirectCast, which doesn't need that "Of".
This should be very clear from the last example.

Comment: Since when does VB support extension methods for type Object?

Comment: @TnTinMn This is not necessarily restricted to only Object but using Object, i can target integers and other types without explicitly referencing them.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a normal function instead of an extension method:

```
Function ToInt(o As Object) As Integer
  Return DirectCast(o, Integer)
End Function
```

The other option is to use the VB type conversion functions: [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vb.cint);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true) (Note, however, that they return new objects - they are not typecasting functions)

Though really, I'd recommend you stick to the built-in `DirectCast` function. All you are really doing is replacing a built-in keyword with a custom keyword that no-one else will recognise.

Comment: Nobody but myself will ever see this code, so having it be readable for me is important.
The VB type conversion functions, as you said, are not typecasting.
A function isn't what i want either. Maybe i should try with a weaver.